# Why does importing module again not updates the module?

Tags: python, import, read-eval-print-loop

I was going through a tutorial on exception handling and had to write this piece of code in module called exception.py

```
def convert(s):
    try:
        x = int(s)
        prnit("Conversion done. x=", x)  #there is a typo
    except ValueError:
        print("Failed")
        x = -1
    return x
```

then from the REPL i import this function as

```
from exception import convert
```

and do
   convert(7.7)
which returned the `NameError: name 'prnit' is not defined` as expected.
After which I corrected typo and did `from exception import convert` again. But the error remained. Why didn't it import new module?

I had to `exit()` then REPL and import it again then it worked fine and as expected.

Comment: It simply caches the imported modules.

Comment: Well. In short, imported modules are cached in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imports are cached in Python, you can read about it in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).

There are ways to invalidate the import cache, but it's strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy: the modules are cached, see the [**Python documentation**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) on the topic (5.3.1).